# How many rounds does an Elo Rating System require to stabilise?

Tags: probability, optimization, algorithms

*the questioner is not a mathematician*

Using an Elo Rating System, or a 'modified' Elo Rating system ...

If I start a competition not knowing participants' relative ability

How many rounds are required before participants' ratings stabilise? (Assuming their relative abilities are constant throughout the competition.)

I reckon it's more complicated than that, so:

How many rounds are required before participants' ratings stabilise to within (10%, 5%, 1%)?

It's also going to depend on the information being used I bet. I'm asking because I'm considering using a modified Elo system for a tennis tournament. So the information used to construct a rating can include:

- matches
- sets
- games

It's also going to depend on the number of participants (I presume, since if there's two participants, their relative ratings will be determined after one round), so 50, 100, 200 participants.

Please accept apologies (and let me know) if this is a badly-posed question. I searched online and while I could find lots of info about Elo's, it was all about Elo's that have been running effectively forever with participants whose abilities change. I found one claim by the operators of a modified Elo (called 'UTR') that 5 rounds are required for a participant's Elo to be 'accurate', but this claim is unsubstantiated.

Comment: I see elsewhere, the term 'round' is used to mean a single match. I used the term to mean a set of matches in which each player plays one match.